# Trouble connecting to SMTP server (PHPmailer)

Tags: php, email, smtp

I have a website that is setup to use PHPmailer to send websites to an email address at the same domain, but I cannot get it to connect to the SMTP server.

This is the part in my config file for the Email:

```
$config = (object) array();

$config->email_from_addr      = "noreply@mywebsite.com";
$config->email_host           = "mail.mywebsite.com";
$config->email_from_password  = '********';
$config->email_from_name      = "Title";

$config->email_to             = 'info@mywebsite.com';
$config->email_subject        = "Contact email from mywebsite";
```

The PHP for sending the email is here:

```
$phpmailer = new PHPMailer();
$phpmailer->IsSMTP();                                             // set mailer to use SMTP
if($config->use_gmail == true)
{
    $phpmailer->Port = 465;
    $phpmailer->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
}
else
{
    $phpmailer->Host = $config->email_host;                 // specify main and backup server
}
$phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;                                // turn on SMTP authentication
$phpmailer->Username = $config->email_from_addr;            // SMTP username
$phpmailer->Password = $config->email_from_password;        // SMTP password

$phpmailer->From = $config->email_from_addr;
$phpmailer->FromName = $config->email_from_name;
$phpmailer->AddAddress($config->email_to);

$phpmailer->WordWrap = 80;                                   // set word wrap to 80 characters
$phpmailer->IsHTML(true);                                    // set email format to HTML

$phpmailer->Subject = $config->email_subject;
$phpmailer->Body    = $message;
$phpmailer->AltBody = $message;

?>
<div style="float:left; display:block; background:#F1F1F1; margin:26px 0 60px 10px; height:200px; padding-top:140px; width:330px; text-align:center; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold" class="red"> 
<?php
if(@!$phpmailer->Send())
{
?>
<br />
<br />
Your email could not be sent.
<?php   
}
else
{
?>
Your email has been sent. Someone will reply to it shortly.
<?php
```

I just don't know why it doesn't connect to my mail server. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Add $phpmailer->SMTPDebug  = 1; and let us know what messages/errors you get.

Comment: Also turn off the error suppression `@` on the line where you are sending the mail you you are not suppressing any errors.

Comment: I got "SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)"

Comment: What SMTP server?  Is "$config->use_gmail" true?  Or are you using some other server?  If it's another server, are you using the right port?

Comment: It is not true, I am using "mail.mywebsite.com" as the SMTP server, and I don't know how to specify the port.

Answer (score 0):

Try `if(!(@$phpmailer->Send()))` instead of `if(@!$phpmailer->Send())`